# I can't put String on the first position of a string array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Please I have a proble, this is my code so far

```
    System.out.println("Please give alue for the table");
    int value = scanner.nextInt();

    String[] StringArray = new String[value];

    for (int i=0; i<value; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please insert string for the position:"+(i+1));
        StringArray[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

And my output is that

```
Please give alue for the table
3
Please insert string for the position:1
Please insert string for the position:2
```

Why i can't insert String to the position 1 and my program goes me in position 2 and after??
Please I need help, I can't unsterstand.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because reading an int does not consume the entire buffer, which still has an `\n` left. As per the documentation, `nextLine` reads until `\n`, so the first time you'll just get an empty string.

You can easily solve this by adding `scanner.nextLine()` right after the `nextInt()`:

```
System.out.println("Please give alue for the table");
int value = scanner.nextInt();

scanner.nextLine(); // get rid of everything else left in the buffer

String[] StringArray = new String[value];

for (int i=0; i<value; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please insert string for the position:"+(i+1));
    StringArray[i] = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: @ILOVEJAVA Don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208693) if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

you can use BufferedReader and InputStreamReader :)

```
System.out.println("Please give alue for the table");
    BufferedReader scanner=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int value = Integer.parseInt(scanner.readLine());
    String[] StringArray = new String[value];

    for (int i=0; i<value; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please insert string for the position:"+(i+1));
        StringArray[i] = scanner.readLine();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time my friend, it will help me this too